# Are there Infinity many natural numbers (that are not factorials) that divide all factorials (greater than that number) evenly?

Tags: number-theory, factorial, factoring

For example:

If n = 12

Then starting at 4! because 3! is less than 12

(4!) % 12 == 0

Therefore (4!) * 5 = (5!) % 12 == 0

etc

and so on until (n-1!) because every factorial after that would obviously be divisible by n.

This is not easy for my (extremely out of date)computer to solve so here is a short list of numbers I have found this to be true for:

1,2,3,6,8,12,24,30,40,60,120,144,180,240,360,720,840,1008,1260,1680,2520, 5040,5760,6720

*arguably 1 2 and 3 should not be included in this list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(n-1)!<N\le n!$ and $n!=mN$. Then
$$
\frac{m}{n} < 1 \le m
$$
and so, apart from 1, these are the numbers of the form $n!/k$ where $k<n,$ given in [A058298](https://oeis.org/A058298).

Answer (score 6):

For $n=12$, you might have stopped with $4!$ right away, because of course $5!=5\cdot 4!$ etc.

First of all, there are infinitely many numbers $n$ such that $k!>n$ does *not* always imply $n\mid k!$. Just consider the case that $n$ is prime, which requires $k\ge n$.

Just as simply, there are infinitely many numbers $n$ for which $k!\ge n$ implies $n\mid k!$. In fact, this is certainly true if $n$ itself is a factorial.

Comment: Definitely a good point as far as calculating these numbers faster, I could easily stop at the first true n | k!. As for the rest, maybe I'm missing something but the rest of what you are saying seems to only say that there are infinity many k!'s. Infinitely many k! >= n, is of course true a number always divides itself. Also it would be assumed that there would be infinity many k! > n where n dose not divide k! hence the short list.

Comment: This is not a non-answer, as your question was if there are infinitely many $n$ such that $k!\ge n$ implies $n\mid k!$. I said that in particular the following infinite sequence of numbers $n$ has this property: $1, 3, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 9!, 10!, 11!, 12!, \ldots$

Comment: my question was are there infinitely many n such that n divides all k! > n. not >= to. But I think I see what your saying, Your saying since this is true  for all factorials there would be infinity many. Maybe my questions is phrased wrong. Are there infinity many n that are also not k!

Comment: You have answers the question that I asked I apologize for the confusion. I think that I am just asking the wrong question. I will reformulate and repost. Thank you for your help.